# Ubuntu VM without iptables and without ip_tables module

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, kernel-modules

I'm using an Ubuntu 16.04 vm at a provider I haven't used before and immediately encountered a new problem. I installed the iptables package, however when I attempted to run `iptables -L`, I received this message:

```
    modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.0-72-generic/modules.dep.bin'
    modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_tables not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-72-generic
    iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
    Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

My first response was to load the ip_tables module, however there were no modules in /lib/modules... I'm also wondering where the kernel config is, since it was not in /boot.

A created a support ticket, but the provider is saying the level of support I'm seeking "requires an SLA agreement".

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

- Run updates:

  ```shell
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
  ```

  If there's a kernel update reboot your system before trying `sudo iptables -L` again.
- Check that `iptables` is built into the kernel:

  ```shell
  grep -i iptables /boot/config-$(uname -r)
  ```

  If the output references something like `*IPTABLES=y` then it's already built in.
- Make sure the module is loaded:

  ```shell
  sudo modprobe ip_tables
  ```
- By default the `iptables` service is disabled. You can start and enable it with:

  ```shell
  sudo systemctl start iptables && sudo systemctl enable iptables
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to convince support to ask an engineer. It was actually stupidly simple:

`apt-get install -y linux-image-$(uname -r)`

Comment: This worked for me.  If you are using a VPS make sure you have selected the correct kernel in your control panel of your service provider.  Here is an example for Digital Ocean: https://serverfault.com/a/782884/446166.